# How to load element into a certain tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

How do I append the `pdfObject` to the div inside my HTML?
I want to use the `document.querySelector` to get the id of the div and then load my PDF into there

here is my javascript function:

```
    showPDF: function (button) {
        let url = document.getElementById("URLinput").value;
        button.style.display = "none";
        let pdfObject = document.createElement("OBJECT");
        pdfObject.setAttribute("data", url);
        pdfObject.setAttribute("id", "pdf");
        let a = document.querySelector(selector)!= null;
        document.a.appendChild(pdfObject);
    },
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/pdfviewer.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PDF Viewer</h1>
  <input id="show" type="button" value="PDF anzeigen" onclick="HM.PDFViewer.showPDF(this)"/>

  <input id="URLinput" type="text" value="/pdf/Doku.pdf"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pdfviewer.js"></script>

  <div id="selector"></div>
  <p> test </p>
</body>
```

Comment: _"but i don't know how"_ - but you have started to write code, apparently - so clearly you must have had _some_ idea. So how exactly is what you tried not actually working then?

Comment: so basically i got some tasks and i did all of them but now i'm stuck on this task and i basically don't know how to use querySelector to load the embedded PDF into tag. I'm sorry that my question is worded badly but i genuinely got no idea what to do

Comment: `embed` is comparable to an `iframe`, in terms of "isolation". If you want to use those pdfviewer script & styles you embedded there, to help display your PDF - then you would need to inject those into an HTML document you load into the embed element instead. But most modern browsers should be capable of displaying PDF, without any such extra external libraries. So I would just try and assign the PDF URL as the source of an iframe, and see what happens.

Comment: but what difference to my question does it make if it's an iframe?

Comment: Probably none, but `embed` is kinda the "ugly duckling" that has fallen out of favor a long time ago, IMHO. That had it uses when there were still things as terrible as JAVA applets out there on the web :-)

Comment: `let a = document.querySelector(selector)!= null; document.a.appendChild(pdfObject);` Here you are setting the variable `a`  to a Boolean value (either `false` or `true`, if `selector` isn't set anywhere then it will point to the element with that id, and `querySelector` will throw because `[object HTMLDivELement]` isn't a valid selector. If `selector` is set to a valid selector though, that one line will do nothing noticeable, because creating an `a` variable doesn't set the `document.a` property.

Comment: As for displaying a pdf in the page, you may want to have a look at [Mozilla's pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) if you want some control over the rendering, be sure it's displayed about the same in all browsers and be sure it's actually displayed in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`EMBED`'s functionality has been standardized in HTML5 and is used to provide containers for plugins. The main problem with `EMBED` is its dependency on plugins to be loaded, which has become less common nowadays.
Instead, you could either use `IFRAME` (which can include HTML pages and possibly other media) or [`OBJECT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object).

Modified version of your code:

```
showPDF: function (button) {
    let url = document.getElementById("URLinput").value;
    button.style.display = "none";
    let pdfObject = document.createElement("OBJECT");
    pdfObject.setAttribute("data", url);
    pdfObject.setAttribute("id", "pdf");
    document.body.appendChild(pdfObject);
}
```

This removes the dependency of having to use browser plugins or external JS libraries while [also being widely supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_object).

Answer (score 0):

The modern browser is a text processor (rather than word processor) which is not a What You Serve Is What You Get (WHSIWYG) editor since the configuration is set by the 7 billion potential users. so here by comparison are Edge on the left and Firefox on the right with my base settings (no extra blockers are used).

Where from < Embed>  < iFrame > and < Object > at least < iFrame> (W3 Recommended) is most consistent giving a download in both Edge and in FireFox, just the same as a traditional A Href=download would do.

[image]

As said each browser can block different aspects so in this one all 3 are blocked evenly so I can download whichever one I wish

[image]

Just to confirm why you cannot enforce a users view of a PDF in their editor here is yet another pdf browser view:-

[image]